# two foreach with $i interference

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert

I have an issue with two foreach loops I am using to insert data into a database.

This is what I currently have:

```
$to_ord = explode("**",  $this->to_ord[$i]);
$i=0;   
foreach ($to_ord as $tord) { 
  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO 
  temporders (order_description) 
      VALUES (:order_description)";             
  $st3 = $conn->prepare ( $sql3 );
  $st3->bindValue( ":order_description", $tord[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st3->execute();
  $i++;
}

$qo_ord = explode("**",  $this->qo_ord[$i]);
$i=0;   
foreach ($qo_ord as $qord) { 
  $sql4 = "INSERT INTO 
  temporders (order_description) 
      VALUES (:order_description)";             
  $st4 = $conn->prepare ( $sql4 );
  $st4->bindValue( ":order_description", $qord[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st4->execute();
  $i++;
}
```

Basically the code gets to sources of information and inserts them into a table. The second one however doesnt run and I have narrowed it down to being the $i and $++ used because if I remove the $i and $i++ from the first one (the first one wont obviously run with out it) the second script will work, but as soon as i put back in the $i the second one wont work again.

Is there away to get around this? The two arrays wont be the same size.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Ian

Comment: Don't you need to reset `$i` before you use it in the `$qo_ord = explode("**",  $this->qo_ord[$i]);` line?

Comment: How have you "narrowed the problem to `$i`"?  When you debug this, how exactly does it fail?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  `$i` is just an incrementing variable, which is being reset before the second loop.  How is it a problem?

Comment: Thanks @Epodax that made me look at that line as opposed to the loop. Moving $qo_ord = explode("**", $this->qo_ord[$i]); along side the first one stopped it being reset.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you maybe misunderstood the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or the [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

I hope I can clarify this, by the below example:

```
$qo_ord = array(
    array( "0 - first value", "0 - second value", "0 - third_value", "0 - fourth value", "0 - fifth value" ),
    array( "1 - first value", "1 - second value", "1 - third_value", "1 - fourth value", "1 - fifth value" ),
    array( "2 - first value", "2 - second value", "2 - third_value", "2 - fourth value", "2 - fifth value" ),
    array( "3 - first value", "3 - second value", "3 - third_value", "3 - fourth value", "3 - fifth value" ),
    array( "4 - first value", "4 - second value", "4 - third_value", "4 - fourth value", "4 - fifth value" ),
);

$i=0;
foreach ( $qo_ord as $qord ) {
    //$qord is now an element of your array ie. in the first loop => array( "0 - first value", "0 - second value"
    echo $qord[$i]."<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

**With the code above you going through the array like this:**

```
|X| | | | |
-----------
| |X| | | |
-----------
| | |X | | |
-----------
| | | |X| |
-----------
| | | | |X|
```

**Next example:**

```
// if you want to get the first item just use [0]
foreach ( $qo_ord as $qord ) {
    //$qord is now an element of your array ie. in the first loop => array( "0 - first value", "0 - second value"
    echo $qord[0]."<br>";
}
```

**With the code above you going through the array like this:**

```
|X| | | | |
-----------
|X| | | | |
-----------
|X| |  | | |
-----------
|X| | | | |
-----------
|X| | | | |
```

Comment: To be honest I tryed simplifiing the question as as oppossed to posting the whole code I have, but I do want it to iterate like you first example as I am actually entering several values from an array. My apologise, tryed to simplify it but failed :(

Comment: No problem, sorry I think I misunderstood something, because your **posted** example does exactly what I described in my first example ;)